# Connect to a socks5 proxy using PyQt4

Tags: python, proxy, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to connect to a socks5 proxy using PyQt4. I can do this using a regular proxy but not a socks5 one (which requires a username and password) using the below code I get an error...

```
TypeError: QNetworkProxy.setPassword(QString): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QNetworkProxy'
```

The code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtWebKit
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *


class Render(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        QNetworkProxy.setPassword('password')
        QNetworkProxy.setUser('user')
        QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(QNetworkProxy(QNetworkProxy.Socks5Proxy, "proxy5.com", 1080))

        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        QtWebKit.QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()
```

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QNetworkProxy.setPassword()` is not a class method but an instance method. So create an instance of QNetworkProxy then set user/password on that:

```
def __init__(self, url):
    networkProxy = QNetworkProxy(QNetworkProxy.Socks5Proxy, "proxy5.com", 1080)
    networkProxy.setPassword('password')
    networkProxy.setUser('user')
    QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(networkProxy)
```

(I've checked the above is correct syntax, but obviously the socks5 host (proxy5.com), port, user and password would have to be correct). If still doesn't work for you, then problem is somewhere else, please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I tried this but still dosen't work.

Comment: it should work, problem is elsewhere, I've edited, can you be more specific about "still doesn't work".

Comment: Hi, Sorry I should have included more details on the error. QT would just start for a second then close. Anyway, I changed the proxy URL for the server IP and it now seems to be working fine. Not 100% sure this was the problem but seems to do the trick now. Thanks for your help. Do you know if there is anyway to ensure QT is connecting via a proxy..?

Comment: @Jim I don't, sorry. So did you have to use the above code or just change the proxy URL in your posted code?

Comment: Hi, I used the code you posted previously, which I think was the same..?

Comment: @Jim yes same, I was wondering because when I put my last comment you hadn't accepted or upvoted the answer yet I was 99% certain the your original code could not work. So you might have had two errors (the one I corrected, and the proxy URL which you corrected). Unless you are saying that in your current setup, you aren't using a proxy because it's URL is the same as server IP?